# Jssor Slider - Hiding Left Navigation arrow on page load

Tags: jquery, jssor

Is there a way to temporary hide the left navigation arrow on initial load?

Much like the slider on apple.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the css property `left-arrow: {visibility: hidden}`, and when your slide jump to 2rd, you can update the property`left-arrow: {visibility: visible}` by javascript.

#### UPDATE:

I wrote a slider demo for you, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/ob9nzpj3/4/

Note that the prev arrow is hidden when you load the html. By clicking the next arrow, the class `.ban` will be removed, so that prev arrow will be visible.

Comment: what will be the trigger? any idea what's the name of the function that triggers sliding/clicking/dragging?

Comment: hey dakk0n, I don't know if you can receive my updated answer, so i send comment here.

Comment: hey abruzzi, thanks for that code! really helped me a lot. btw, can't upvote your answer as I dont have enough reputation.